# Can I set an image, pixel by pixel, in Apps Script?

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-docs

Preferably, I'd like to use an array, iterating over each pixel and setting the R G B values.

And I don't think that I can use HTML canvas in any way. I'm hoping to build it right on top of  a Google Doc without additional libraries or references to external websites.

Everything I have found on the [Image Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/image), type is about positioning or resizing, but not helpful for stating the image.

[ImageItem .setImage()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/image-item#setImage(BlobSource)) looks promising, but is not particularly descriptive.

Comment: You need to create a [jpeg](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) structure as a byte array, which can be converted to a blob and used in setImage.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own encoding algorithm (or migrate [someone else's](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpeg-js)) and transform your pixels array into an image blob compatible with the [`ImageItem.setImage()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/image-item#setimageimage) method.